# PythonCode.py is working fine but pythonCode.exe is not

Tags: python, python-requests, exe

I have a python code that has GUI and then send some information to a server.
When I run this code from Cmd it works properly.
But when I transform it to exe and run the exe by double clicking, it doesn't work. The GUI opens but nothing being sent to the server.
When I run the exe from cmd I'm getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "pythonCode.py", line 168, in <module>
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\warnings.py", line 15, in showwarning
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\warnings.py", line 23, in formatwarning
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\linecache.py", line 15, in getline
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\linecache.py", line 41, in getlines
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\linecache.py", line 126, in updatecache
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\tokenize.py", line 438, in open
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\tokenize.py", line 416, in detect_encoding
File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\tokenize.py", line 380, in find_cookie
SyntaxError: invalid or missing encoding declaration for 'pythonCode.exe
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: How did you transform it to exe ??

Comment: with `cx_freeze`

Comment: Siba, try to add encoding declaration on top of you .py file like here - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: I added it but it didn't work. Any other ideas?Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there was (divide by zero exception) in my code that I didn't handle.
And another error with "requests" package that I solved this way:
I copied the cacert.pem file from /lib/site-packages/certifi to /lib/site-packages/requests and to build/library.zip/certifi/.

Thanks all